# How should you use UnitofWork pattern on my asp.net-mvc site (using nhibernate and ninject)

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, ioc-container, ninject, unit-of-work

i have [followed the pattern on this site](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/) to hook up ninject and nhibernate to my asp.net-mvc3 site.

Here is the code in my global.aspx.cs:

```
 internal class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        var helper = new NHibernateHelper(connectionString);
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory)
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>()
            .InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider())
            .InRequestScope();
        Bind<IIntKeyedRepository<FAQ>>().To<Repository<FAQ>>()
            .InRequestScope();
       }
```

the issue is that i now need to do Update() and Add() in my controllers;

I have this as my controller code:

```
    public FAQController(IIntKeyedRepository<FAQ> faqRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _faqRepository = faqRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }


  [Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult AddFAQ(FAQ contact)
    {
        var c = new FAQ {Question = contact.Question, Answer = contact.Answer};
        _faqRepository.Add(c);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

my main question is that it feels wrong to pass in Iunitofwork in the constructor as many other actions don't need it.  I only really need it for the actions where i do updates and inserts into my db.  Since i am using ninject IOC on the link above it seems to say to pass this unitofwork object through IOC.

So, is there a better more optimized way to using the UnitOfWork pattern with IOC in asp.net-mvc that does call beingtransaction for every method in my controller.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://blog.xelibrion.com/journal/2011/4/16/nhibernate-session-management-in-aspnet-mvc-application.html) blog post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative way to handle transactions is to use an `IActionFilter` Open the transaction in `OnActionExecuting` and commit on `OnActionExecuted`

```
public class TransactionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ISession session;
    private ITransaction transaction;

    public TransactionFilter(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        this.transaction = this.session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.transaction.IsActive)
            {
                if (filterContext.Exception == null)
                {
                    this.transaction.Commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    this.transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Define an attribute to mark the actions that use a transaction:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class TransactionAttribute : Attribute
{ 
}
```

Change your Ninject configuration:

```
internal class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        var helper = new NHibernateHelper(connectionString);
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory)
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>().ToProvider<SessionProvider>().InRequestScope();
        Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
        Bind(typeof(IIntKeyedRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
        BindFilter<TransactionFilter>(FilterScope.Action, null)
            .WhenActionMethodHas<TransactionAttribute>();
    }
}
```

Finally change your controller:

```
public FAQController(IIntKeyedRepository<FAQ> faqRepository)
{
    _faqRepository = faqRepository;
}


[Transaction]
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult AddFAQ(FAQ contact)
{
    var c = new FAQ {Question = contact.Question, Answer = contact.Answer};
    _faqRepository.Add(c);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Ayende proposed almost the same solution: http://ayende.com/blog/4809/refactoring-toward-frictionless-odorless-code-what-about-transactions But I prefer injecting the session over requesting from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try to keep my generic IRepository implementation hidden inside the IUnitOfWork (see below).

My other recommendation is to pass a UnitOfWorkProvider or UnitOfWorkFactory to the constructor. That way you can register the transaction scope locally. This has the added benefit of being able to resolve the IRepository or ISession as you see fit, via dependency injection or manually.

```
using(var uow = this.UnitOfWorkProvider.New())
{
    uow.Save<Faq>(myFaq);
}
```

Also make sure you in your IUnitOfWork.Dispose() you clean up the transaction and any data session objects / information you might have.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to only inject my unit of work into classes that actually use them. In most cases, the persistence classes (Repository in my case) are the only ones that need the unit of work. You want to make sure you maintain a clean separation of concerns. The controller doesn't need to know about the unit of work and shouldn't be coupled to it, either.

```
public class FaqRepository {
  public FaqRepository(IUnitOfWork unitofWork) { ... }

  public void CreateQuestion(Faq faq) {
    unitOfWork.Save(faq);
    unitOfWork.Commit();
  }
}
```

If you're invoking your repository from your controller, inject the repository into your controller as follows:

```
public class FaqController {
  public FaqController(IFaqRepository faqRepository) {...}
}
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: The problem I see with this is that your Repository is now responsible for the UoW. If you needed to make changes that required two repositories you're going to run into problems.

Comment: If your UoW falls across two objects, say, UserLogin and UserProfile being stored separately, no cascade, it's across two repositories, and you want to run both within the transaction. Your repository currently commits the transaction, so you need to run up two separate Units of Work.

Comment: @Phil Makes sense. Where would you handle this transaction? Is this something you'd do in your service/business layer? Does it make sense for the service/business layer to take a dependency on your UoW just so that it can manage transactions? What if you implemented the session-per-request pattern along with having a transaction open for the duration of the request?

Comment: The way I handle it is on an Action by Action basis. In my BaseController i override OnActionExecuting to create a new UnitOfWork, and override OnActionExecuted I call Commit. I pass the UnitOfWork to the methods (Service and/or Repositories) that use it. Oh and OnException I roll the commit back :)

Comment: Chuck me an email to blog [at] philliphaydon.com and I'll send you my BaseController so you can see.